# Tabs not detected after open new Firefox window

Tags: tabs, firefox-addon, require, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm working on a Java project and we realized an add-on for firefox 17 ESR with the SDK 1.10.
Today I have to modify our add-on to work with Firefox 24 ESR. I decided to use the SDK 1.15.

Our application has to open 3 new windows. Here is the native code we use:

```
private static native void openUrlAfterDelay(String url, String windowName, int delay)
/*-{
   $wnd.setTimeout(function() { $wnd.open(url, windowName, "location=no") }, delay);
}-*/;
```

In the add-on, we need to list all tabs. We use this code:

```
var tabs = require('tabs');
for each (var tab in tabs) {
    var worker = tab.attach({
          contentScriptFile:
            data.url("xxxxxxx.js")
      });
}
```

In Firefox 17 with SDK 1.10 -> all works
In Firefox 24 with SDK 1.15 -> The new windows/tabs are not detected

Has anyone a solution?

Comment: Your question is missing important information: 1) When exactly are you running the code to list tabs (e.g.: immediately after opening new window, on a timeout etc.), 2) How are you opening new browser windows? Also, I assume that the "native code" part belongs to some code generation framework that you don't mention - you should include the generated JavaScript code instead.

Comment: First line should be `var tabs = require('sdk/tabs')`